# How to use consts in Lajax manager in Yii2

Tags: php, internationalization, yii2, constants

I am trying to use const in my Lajax translate manager. But, the built-in scan function does not works with `const`. It just does not see `const` while scanning.

```
$emailObject->subject = Yii::t(LC::MAIL, LT::TEXT);
```

How can I do it with `const`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior as the scanner parses the PHP (and JS files, as per config) for literal occurrences of the pattern `t::('tag', 'Message')` and related patterns.

The details can be gleaned from the source: [ScannerFile.php](https://github.com/lajax/yii2-translate-manager/blob/master/services/scanners/ScannerFile.php)

```
* Language elements detected in PHP files:
 *
 * "t" functions:
 * ::t('category of language element', 'language element');
 * ::t('category of language element', 'language element {replace}', ['replace' => 'String']);
 * ::t('category of language element', "language element");
 * ::t('category of language element', "language element {replace}", ['replace' => 'String']);
```

You might be able to override this behavior by implementing your own scannerfile if needed...